# JSoup check if <HTML>,<HEAD> and <BODY> tags are present

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup, html-parser

Hi I am using JSoup to parse a HTML file. After parsing, I want to check if the file contains the  tag. I am using the following code to check that,

```
htmlDom = parser.parse("<p>My First Heading</p><a href=\"www.google.com\">clk</a>");
Elements pe = htmlDom.select("html");
System.out.println("size  "+pe.size());
```

The output I get is "size 1" even though there is no HTML tag present. My guess is that it is because the HTML tag is not mandatory and that it is implicit. Same is the case for Head and Body tag. Is there any way I could check for sure if these tags are present in the input file?

Thank you.

Comment: You are right, it returns 1 because they are implicit, and I don't think jsoup will provide a way to check if they actually exists.. You will have to use basic string match or regular expressions for that.

Comment: Yes regex was my plan B. just wanted to make sure that there was no other way of doing it using JSoup.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not return `1` because the tag is implicit, but because it **is** present in the `Document` object `htmlDom` after you have parsed the custom HTML.

That is because Jsoup will try to conform the [HTML5 Parsing Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/parsing.html), and thus adds missing elements and tries to fix a broken document structure. I'm quite sure you would get a `1` in return if you were to run the following aswell:

```
Elements pe = htmlDom.select("head");
System.out.println("size  "+pe.size());
```

To parse the HTML without Jsoup trying to clean or make your HTML valid, you can instead use the included `XMLParser`, as below, which will parse the HTML as it is.

```
String customHtml = "<p>My First Heading</p><a href=\"www.google.com\">clk</a>";
Document customDoc = Jsoup.parse(customHtml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

So, as opposed to your assumption in the comments of the question, this is very much possible to do with Jsoup.